# Enabled Hint but wont Display, Cursor too wont show as user inputs name an password

Tags: android, xml

Sorry again for posting this question but the previous did not give me any answer. So my dilemma is i can not get to create a line between my log in, I am also unable to get my Hint Email to display. I also want the user to able to type in as they see the cursor blinking as they fill their email and password.

This is what i want to achieve

[image]

This is my entire Xml, I know this is local but i will appreciate any guidelines and steps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_normal">


    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:hintEnabled="true"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="55dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/logintoproceed"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/signup"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                android:text="@string/create"
                android:textSize="16dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgotpass"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                android:text="@string/forgotpassword"
                android:textSize="16dip" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i am not getting your point. you want blue line at bottom of ediitext and color of cursor ? right ?

Comment: in question your scroll view is missing `>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Your Background color is overriding the hint text color . try to give an accent color for hint text.

Answer (score 2):

Try to give textcolorhint in TextInputLayout

```
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signup_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
            android:hint="@string/email_id"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            />
         </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <style name="TextLabel" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/secondary_text</item>
</style>
```

Apply theme in your xml

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextInputLayout` for hint color and also apply material theme.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/blach"/>

         </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Hope it will help you!!